# Demonstration of the largest product between segments

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this statement:

Let $f: \mathbb{R}-\{-1\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ Defined by: $f(x) = \frac{|x+2|-x}{x+1}$. Is this function injective?

My attempt was:

I know that if a function $f$ is injective, is true that if $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, then $x_1 = x_2$

Then, if i find a counterxample to that,  mean that $f$ isn't injective. But i can't find any counterexample, but neither i can prove that is injective.

Im newbie in this topic. So my doubt is:

How i can solve this type of exercise? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The way to come up with the solution by Azif00 is to simplify the function. An absolute value is generally not 'simple', so you find the values of $x$ that correspond to where the argument of the absolute value function is positive/negative, and try to simplify the expression based on that.

In our case, the absolute value is $|x+2|$, so we have to look at 2 cases:

$$x \ge -2,$$
$$x < -2.$$

In the first case ($x \ge -2$), we have $|x+2| = x+2$, so we get

$$\text{If }x \ge -2 \text{, then } f(x)=\frac{(x+2)-x}{x+1} = \frac2{x+1}$$

So you may or may not have an idea if that part of the function is injective, but it's certainly a more simple description than the original formulation.

In the second case ($x < -2$) we have $|x+2| = -(x+2)$, so we get

$$\text{If }x < -2 \text{, then } f(x)=\frac{-(x+2)-x}{x+1} = \frac{-2x-2}{x+1} =-2$$

So, this part of the function is certainly not injective, it's kinda the opposite: The value of the function is the same for all $x < -2$.

That's why Azif00 asked you to evaluate $f(-2), f(-3), f(-4)$, they knew that the function values would all be the same ($-2$), which exactly gives you a counterexample.

Of course, such problems are not always that easy. Generally you may need to apply methods from calculus, but in this case, it got easy because the simplification showed that for $x< -2$ the function was really easy to understand!

Answer (score 1):

Try with $f(-2)$, $f(-3)$, $f(-4)$ and so on...

Comment: This don't help me

Comment: We have that $f(-2)=f(-3)$ but $-2\neq -3$. Thus, $f$ cannot be injective.

Comment: Ok, but how to solve this problem in general without calculus?

Comment: @EduardoS. How is this calculus? Azif$00$ told you to plug in numbers which you weren't willing to do. Often the way to solve these problems is by looking at cases.

Comment: You were looking for "counterexamples." I gave you one. By the way, this does not use calculus at all, these are only simply *functions*.